# private[foo] apply to any foo based package?

Tags: scala, scope, package

A long shot, but putting it out there -- looking for a way to provide privacy based on a common relative package scope.

So, for example, is there a way to use `private[foo]` for packages `com.company1.foo` and `com.company2.foo` where each package will have access to the other foo package based on their "foo-ness"

Unlikely, but would be nice, have a `private[model]` used in dependent sbt projects that could really benefit from such a relative privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.  From the language spec (2.9):

> The modiﬁer can be qualiﬁed with an identiﬁer `C` (e.g. `private[C]`) that must
>   denote a class or package enclosing the deﬁnition

So the best you can hope for is a shared common package.  For the two given examples, `com.company1.foo`, and `com.company2.foo` the most restrictive shared root is `com`; `private[com]` would be the best you could do.

Comment: +1 yeah, figured as much -- "private[com]" is a bit wide open ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, since `foo` is just an alias for one specific fully named package in any given scope.

So to packages with names ending in `.foo` don't have much more in common than two packages containing the letter `e` in their names.